# Reducir cantidad de condicionales

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, condiciones

Tengo una pequeña función que entrega el valor que tiene prioridad mayor, la cual por ahora no está definida en ninguna parte, tan solo por el orden según evaluo los valores:

```
public function obtenerValorMasImportante($datos = null) {

    if ($datos->getDato1()) {
        return 'dato1';
    }
    if ($datos->getDatoX()) {
        return 'datox';
    }
    if ($datos->getLoQueSea()) {
        return 'loquesea';
    }
    if ($datos->getOtraCosa()) {
        return 'otracosa';
    }
    return false;
}
```

El problema es sencillo: el código funciona, pero **¿Qué pasa si tengo 100 valores?** tendría que escribir 100 `if` y no es una buena idea, no me fluyen tampoco las ideas en este momento del día.

No tengo mayor control sobre el objeto `$datos`, entonces no es una opción modificarlo o agregarle información.

**¿Cómo podría reducir la cantidad de if? o en su defecto hacer el código independiente de la cantidad de valores.**

Comment: ¿Y si intentas hacerlo con un switch? 
`switch (n) {
    case 1:
       //TODO
        break;
    case 2:
       //TODO
        break;
    case 3:
       //TODO
        break;
    ...
    default:
       //TODO
}`

Comment: ¿Siempre son valores que debes llamar en base a funciones propias del objeto como muestras aquí o que puede que no existan?

Comment: @x4mp73r usando `switch` también tendrías que escribir 100 `case`s y al parecer Shaz quiere evitar escribir los 100 `if`s o `case`s.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza las funciones son "magic getters", en este caso `dato1`, `datox` y las demás son propiedades del objeto, por ende no existen como tal dichos métodos. La pregunta podría hacerse incluso cambiando el objeto $datos por un arreglo, pero que no se puede modificar, ni teniendo en cuenta los keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en las respuestas proporcionadas por Álvaro y Jesús (nuevas respuestas son bienvenidas), terminé utilizando este código, usando [funciones variables](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
public function obtenerValorMasImportante($datos = null) {

    $valores = ['Dato1', 'DatoX', 'LoQueSea', 'OtraCosa'];

    foreach ($valores as $valor) {
        $metodo = 'get' . $valor;

        if ($datos->{$metodo}()) {
            return strtolower($valor);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muy bien, tres respuestas diferentes. La verdad es que ésta es la que más me gusta de las tres porque se ve más limpia y ordenada.

Comment: Coincido con Alvaro, es muy sencilla, hace el trabajo y no introduce problemas de seguridad pues los valores y métodos están en un array conocido.

Answer (score 5):

No se trata de que `eval` sea "malo", otra desventaja es que [no puedes capturar errores fácilmente](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php), y el código no es portable a PHP 7, ya que forzosamente se debe incluir una sentencia `return` o devolverá NULL.

Además, no es necerio usar `eval`. Puedes llamar dinámicamente un método con `call_user_func`.

Aunque en el ejemplo el nombre del método y el valor de retorno están a un 'get' menos en la cadena y devolviendo `strtolower($nombre_metodo)`, supongamos que no es así, y que tenemos que mapear nombres de métodos invocados a valores dispares:

```
function obtenerValor($datos = null) {    
    $mapMetodoAValor = [
        'Dato1' => 'valorRetorno1',
        'DatoX' => 'valorRetornoOtro',
        /* siguen más metodos => valor ...*/
    ];
    foreach($mapMetodoAValor as $metodo => $valor) {
        if(call_user_func([$datos, 'get' . $metodo])) {
            return $valor;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Si los valores siempre son iguales a `strtolower($metodo)` el array puede ser más simple, como el ejemplo de Álvaro, pero de nuevo, no hay ninguna necesidad de usar eval. Siempre prefiere [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 4):

Como todos los condicionales tienen la misma estructura básica, éste es un caso en el que podrías usar [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php). La idea sería que cambiases la función para que hiciera algo como esto:

1. Crea un array con una lista (ordenada por orden de prioridad) con los nombres de los atributos a comprobar
2. Atraviesa la lista desde el primer elemento al último

   1. Con `eval` asigna el valor del *getter* a una variable auxiliar
   2. Comprueba el valor de la variable auxiliar
   3. Si tiene algún valor, devuelve el nombre del elemento del array.

El código sería así:

```
function obtenerValorMasImportante($datos = null) {    
    $aux = array("Dato1", "DatoX", "LoQueSea", "OtraCosa");
    $val = null;
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($aux); $x++) {
        eval('$val = $datos->get' . $aux[$x] . '();');
        if ($val)
            return strtolower($aux[$x]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Entonces ahora lo único que tienes que mantener es la lista de atributos ordenados por prioridad.

Sí, sé que habrá gente que dirá "*pero `eval` es diabólico y no debe usarse*", pero eso no es del todo correcto, especialmente para este caso porque tú estarás al control de todo lo que se va a evaluar, por lo que no corres los riesgos de hacer un `eval` con una entrada desconocida.

Comment: Andaba pensando en una solución así, definiendo el array al inicio, gracias! voy a esperar si hay más respuestas y publicaré la idea que tengo. :)

Comment: No es necesario usar eval, [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php) es una mejor opción. Pongo ejemplo en respuesta aparte.

Comment: @JesúsFranco genial. Gracias, no conocía ese método.  Todos los días se aprende algo 

Comment: Aunque tu ejemplo es genial, lo tomé como base para mi respuesta. No me atreví a editar tu respuesta por la argumentación a favor de `eval`. O dejaba los argumentos haciendo confuso el código, o eliminaba los argumentos adulterando por completo la respuesta.